# Unmanaged Exports System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, missingmethodexception, unmanagedexports

I have two functions getStatus() and checkStatus() that I have exposed using UnmanagedExports. I can successfully call them separately from C++ code. But when I call the first function getStatus() from inside the second function checkStatus() I get MissingMethodException. Following code for independent functions works fine:

```
[DllExport(ExportName = "GetStatusMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static string getStatus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string Url)
{
    string status;
    //performing some action
    return status;
}

[DllExport(ExportName = "CheckStatusMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static string checkStatus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string someStr)
{
    string status;
    //performing some action
    return status;
}
```

Following throws MissingMethodException:

```
[DllExport(ExportName = "GetStatusMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static string getStatus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string Url)
{
    string status;
    //performing some action
    return status;
}

[DllExport(ExportName = "CheckStatusMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static string checkStatus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string someStr)
{
    return getStatus();// throws MissingMethodException
}
```

How to call a function (that is exposed using UnmanagedExports) from within another exposed function in c#?

Comment: Your test program is using an old copy of the assembly.  Pretty typical since you often have to copy the DLL so the test program can find it back.  Be sure to update the copy.

Comment: @HansPassant I have made sure that the copy is updated, still the issue